# Wrong payment currency with Paypal in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, paypal, currency

In WooCommerce, I have a dropdown to change the currency.

On the checkout page, the prices are in pounds, but when paying with PayPal, it gives me euros.

I tried using:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_currency', 'change_existing_currency', 10, 1);
function change_existing_currency( $currency ) {
  $currency = 'GBP';

  return $currency;
}
```

But It doesn't solve the problem.

Is there a function or a hook to change the payment currency?

###### The product details:

[image: the product details]

---

###### Paying with PayPal:

[image: paying with PayPal]

Comment: I see you got downvoted, dont know why but speaking about WordPress, 
stackoverflow probably is not the right place where to ask this question. Try here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @dev-chicco All WordPress plugins (including WooCommerce) are off-topic in WordPress Stack Exchange (only pure WordPress questions are allowed)… So Stack OverFlow is the right place for WooCommerce tagged questions.

Comment: As there are many different payments PayPal plugins for WooCommerce, you should specify which one you are using. Also, if you are using a currency converter plugin you should mention which one. Nobody can guess things by magic.

Comment: I think they have to close some questions then https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/371610/how-to-add-a-user-custom-field-into-woocommerce-emails